Is this a good power point tracking setup for a PV system?
I have a PV system with 88 x 410 Wp modules arranged into east and west facing sections, with 6 strings (indicated with colors) set up the following way (Google Maps link of the site, though the system can only be seen on historical Google Earth imagery):

The number of modules per strings is the following:

string 1: 14 east facing modules
string 2: 14 west facing modules
string 3: 25 east facing modules
string 4: 25 west facing modules
string 6: 5 east facing modules
string 8: 5 west facing modules

According to simulations, this is the expected yearly irradiance of the site:

My inverter (a HUAWEI SUN2000-30KTL-M3) is capable of tracking 4 separate power points, and the installer has connected the strings to the inverter so that:

MPPT1 -- strings 1 & 2
MPPT2 -- strings 3 & 4
MPPT3 -- string 6
MPPT4 -- string 8

(the slots for string 5 and 7 are not connected on the inverter).
My current voltage and current curves for a perfectly sunny day are the following for this setup:


My questions is whether this is a sensible setup of the power point tracking? I am not an expert but dedicating individual power point tracking to the two smallest and least irradiated strings does not seem to be a good choice to me. On what basis should the strings be matched for power point tracking? Orientation (east, west) or the characteristics of the current curve (similar curved strings should go together)?
Any advice would be highly appreciated.
